# Task distribution for graph based data

Tags: variable-assignment, task, cluster-computing

I am learning to program distributed computing system. And the system I need to work on would require to perform computation on graph data (social network data) in parallel environment.

After searching on the internet, I come down to the issue regarding to the task distribution. It seems that many of such kind systems are designed by worker requesting task from master e.g. volunteer computing [1] or hadoop map/reduce transmit heartbeat.

My question is - is there any task distribution/ assignment is designed with the style in that the master would proactive assign task to slaves? What issues may need to pay attention to when programming such mechanism?

I think I may be wrong in some concepts that I am not aware of. So I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks for advice.

[1]. boinc.berkeley.edu/heien_09.pdf

Answer (score 0):

No, you're exactly right -- the master-wokrer pattern is well established. For a certain flavour of it, take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/14/best-practices-for-maximizing-scalability-and-cost-effectiveness-of-queue-based-messaging-solutions-on-windows-azure.aspx) for a message-queue based system, or look it up on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

Thanks for providing that link. Although it talks about Microsoft solution, the information in the article is very useful, which serves as good keywords for me to  search further information.

Thanks again for your help!